# Installing a dashboard camera

Tags: installation, dash, accessories

Is it possible to power a dash cam from the ceiling console on a 2014 Ford Fusion.

Answer (score 3):

If there's a power supply then more than likely yes, check the voltage required for the dash cam against the voltage supplied in the ceiling console first though, if the voltages are the same you could splice into the wires for the interior lights(presume it has them in the ceiling console).

If not you could do what I did and get an extra long cable for the dashcam and run it down the side of the car by tucking the wire under the windscreen pillar panels and then go under the dashboard and just plug it into the cigarette lighter(presuming your dashcam has a cigarette plug and not a usb one)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the voltages are the same - they are both likely to be 12 volts.

You can get spade connectors to stick in the terminals between the bulb without issue. The wattage of running both the light and the dashcam may be the only real issue you have. In that case, remove the bulb.

A few places sell "fake" bulbs that are a negative and positive electrical connection that is spring loaded to fit most interior bulb sockets.